# Post an image from code to Blobstore on appengine?

Tags: google-app-engine, http-post, blobstore

I am trying to post an image which I am downloading using URLFetch() to the blobstore.

Basically, for any given youtube video, i am first fetching the thumbnail from youtube's site and then I want to store it in the blobstore ...

can anyone help me with this?

I am using the poster moduler for the form multi=part stuff as detailed on the last comment of this post

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=627

Comment: I'll just delete this account and create another :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the blobstore to store such a small image. Just store it as a BlobProperty on a regular datastore model, and serve it up from there.